# repeatedly add 4 to an integer a certain amount of times

Tags: loops

The program should print a single line of output with integers starting with n, and then the integers resulting from repeatedly adding 4 as many times as specified by times.

EDIT: My question is, How can I have the program count up by 4 a certain amount of times? An example would be entering 9 (the starting value) and 5 (the amount of times by 4) 9 13 17 21 25 29

```
int main(void) {
    // TODO: add your code here
    int n;
    int times;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&times);
     for(int i = n; i <= times; i += 4){
        printf("%i ", times);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing `times` (which doesn't change value) in the loop, how about printing the start value plus 4 for every time the loop has iterated:

```
int main(void) {
    int start;
    int times;
    scanf("%i",&start);
    scanf("%i",&times);
    for(int i = 0; i <= times; i++){
        printf("%i ", start + (i * 4));
    }
    return 0;
}
```